# Play Java - Is there a way access response in filter /print/log response body

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get response body in filter for PlayFramework in Java. I'm new to Java and Play and learning through logging filter from https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHttpFilters .

`Result.body()` is a `HttpEntity`, how can I access the result body without having to consume the data?

```java
public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
      Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return nextFilter
        .apply(requestHeader)
        .thenApply(
            result -> {
              long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              long requestTime = endTime - startTime;

              log.info(
                  "{} {} took {}ms and returned {}",
                  requestHeader.method(),
                  result.body(), //Json Response
                  result.status());

              return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + requestTime);
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Play provides a lower level filter API called EssentialFilter that gives you full access to the body of the request. This API allows you to wrap EssentialAction with another action.

More info here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHttpFilters#More-powerful-filters